# passing data from one table view cell to another table cell using segue iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard, segue

I have a table view with rows X,Y,Z.What I want is when user select X it should show me another child table view with rows X1,X2,X3; when user select Y its should load another child table view with rows Y1,Y2,Y3 and so for Z.
Here is what I'm doing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
arrOEMs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
OEMs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"X",@"Y",@"Z", nil];
//NSDictionary *oemDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:OEMs forKey:@"OEMs"];
//[arrOEMs addObject:oemDict];
childrenof1stOEM = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"X1",@"X2",@"X3", nil];
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row == 0) 
{
    NSLog(@"1st selected");
   //show X1,X2,X3 in another table view
   passIndexPath = indexPath;
   //NSDictionary *dictinary = [arrOEMs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
   //NSArray *array = [dictinary objectForKey:@"OEMs"];
   //selectedOEMs = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OEMDetailsConnectorSegue" sender:self];
}
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    NSLog(@"2 selected");
  //Show Y1,Y2,Y3 in another table view
}
if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    NSLog(@"3 selected");
}
```

Calling segue like following:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"OEMDetailsConnectorSegue"])
{
     //NSLog(@"2 selected");

   OEMsDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    //destViewController.OemNames = self.selectedOEMs; //showing exception at this step
    //destViewController.parentIndex = passIndexPath;
    if (passIndexPath.row == 0) {
       destViewController.childData = [childrenof1stOEM objectAtIndex:passIndexPath.row];
    }
}
}
```

"childrenof1stOEM " is not getting assigned to "childData"...Also
how can I assign "childData" to next table view cell.It seems that I have not assigned so throwing exception, what I'm doing wrong?Could any one plaese modify my code to make it work or provide me some link??

Comment: What kind of exeption? Where is `childrenof1stOEM`defined?

Comment: What exception says ?

Comment: Modified my code to show "childrenof1stOEM".I'm getting SIGABRT exception in main.